# Concatenate coffeescript files in correct order using Elixir

Tags: javascript, laravel, coffeescript, gulp, laravel-elixir

I'm using [Elixir](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/elixir) to concatenate and compile Coffeescript files into Javascript. When I try to call a function from a place that originally is in another file, I get an error saying that the function doesn't exist. This is because the compilation splits up the different files into different scopes. How do I solve this?

This is how I currently compile the code

```
elixir(function(mix) {
    mix.coffee([
        'app.coffee',
        'tags.coffee',
    ]);
});
```